# Слитно или через дефис пишутся слова с «убер»?

Tags: орфография, лексика, заимствования, приставка, слитно-дефис

Скажите, пожалуйста, слитно или через дефис пишутся слова с "убер": убер(-)солдат, убер(-)оружие и т. д.?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно, такой приставки, как "убер", в словарях не зафиксировано.
Осмелюсь предположить, что будет действовать закон аналогии, согласно которому заимствованная немецкая приставка будет писаться так же, как и подобные ей: -обер, штабс, лейб, унтер и т.п. Я бы рекомендовал писать через дефис

> убер-солдат, убер-оружие.

Answer (score 1):

В Википедии нашлось вот что ([**uber**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uber)):

> В немецком языке «über» означает: «над» или «сверху», часто используется как приставка для обозначения повышенного уровня или превосходной степени. В США «uber» в первой половине XX века превратилось в сленговый вариант слова «super». Первоначальное название компании «UberCab» на русский можно перевести как «СуперТакси».

Думаю, что на правописание приставок [***супер-***](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80) (суперсолдат, супероружие) и ***сверх-*** (сверхсолдат, сверхоружие) и надо ориентироваться, то есть писать слова слитно (тем более что по значению и употреблению они ведь очень схожи).

*Ах да, если вы думали, что став упырем, ты будешь непобедим, как **уберсолдат**, то ошибаетесь...* (Георгий Чернов. Имитация).
*Игра вернулась к прежнему формату – злобный **уберсолдат** стрелял голубыми молниями* (Стасс Бабицкий. Без пяти лет апокалипсис).

*Наши власти живут в сладких грёзах, когда явятся пришельцы и сунут им в руки **убероружие**, с помощью которого они наведут порядок на планете...* (Сергей Панченко. Я стираю свою тень).
*В свое время это **убероружие** было настолько популярным и массовым, что никто не удосужился его описать* (Николай Берг. Ночная смена. Остров живых).